# SQL update rows if duplicate values exists

Tags: sql, psql

Basically, to simplify the problem, I want to take a table like this:

```
VALUE | OTHER
----- | -----
a     | null
b     | null
c     | null
c     | null
d     | null
e     | null
```

and update only both the `c` row's (because duplicate value) "OTHER" field to "duplicate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify the name of the table so I've called it `table1`. The key part is using the `having` statement with `group by` to identify the duplicates (rows with a count > 1):

```
update table1 set OTHER = 'duplicate' where "value" in 
(select "value" from table1 group by "value" having count("value")>1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c3df5/4/1

Answer (score 1):

using any clause to solve the problem.

```
with a as 
(select "value" from table1 group by 1 having count("value") >1)
update table1 set OTHER = 'duplicated' where "value" = any(a);
```